# Xcode 12.5 - How to enlarge debugger font?

Tags: xcode

I am mildly visually impaired and couldn't find it under "Themes" where the code editor's font size was buried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the Console Tab and select an option you want to change (typically Executable Console Output and Debugger Console Output appear in the debugger). Now click the tiny little T icon at the bottom and change the font to something more palatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can click inside the console and push "Command +"